# Distant relationship, select brands that products use

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on an ecommerce app, and I have the following tables:

`products:
id, name, description, category_id, brand_id, sku, created_at... etc`

`brands:
id, name`

`categories:
id,name,parent_id`

Say I have this, to retrieve products with those categories, how will I also retrieve all brands that products use without having duplicates? Since different products can have the same brand, so it won't be displayed in the filtering sidebar.

`$products = Product::whereIn('category_id', [1, 2, 3])->get();`

Answer (score 0):

To select distinct brand_id, `distinct()` method can be used on the query builder.

Possible use on Product could be:

```
$products = Product
    ::distinct()
    ->select('brand_id')
    ->whereIn('category_id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->get();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    print "{$product->brand->name}, ";
}
```